# How can i transparent from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, fragment, expandable

Now I'm trying to the transparent opensource expandable layout but the problem is that source made by activity but I want to apply my fragment layout what should I do? 
When I try to transparent it's occurred error...

****This is what I want to try transparent****

```
package com.expandablelistdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import com.expandablelistdemo.Model.DataItem;
import com.expandablelistdemo.Model.SubCategoryItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn;
private ExpandableListView lvCategory;

private ArrayList<DataItem> arCategory;
private ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> arSubCategory;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategoryItem>> arSubCategoryFinal;

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems;
private MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CheckedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    setupReferences();
}

private void setupReferences() {

    lvCategory = findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);
    arCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    parentItems = new ArrayList<>();
    childItems = new ArrayList<>();

    DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("1");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Adventure");

    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

        SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
        subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(i));
        subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
        subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Adventure: "+i);
        arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }
    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("2");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Art");
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {

        SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
        subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(j));
        subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
        subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Art: "+j);
        arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }
    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("3");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Cooking");
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int k = 1; k < 6; k++) {

        SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
        subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(k));
        subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
        subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Cooking: "+k);
        arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }

    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    Log.d("TAG", "setupReferences: "+arCategory.size());

    for(DataItem data : arCategory){
//                        Log.i("Item id",item.id);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childArrayList =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> mapParent = new HashMap<String, String>();

        mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID,data.getCategoryId());
        mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME,data.getCategoryName());

        int countIsChecked = 0;
        for(SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem : data.getSubCategory()) {

            HashMap<String, String> mapChild = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_ID,subCategoryItem.getSubId());
            mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_NAME,subCategoryItem.getSubCategoryName());
            mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID,subCategoryItem.getCategoryId());
            mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED,subCategoryItem.getIsChecked());

            if(subCategoryItem.getIsChecked().equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {

                countIsChecked++;
            }
            childArrayList.add(mapChild);
        }

        if(countIsChecked == data.getSubCategory().size()) {

            data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
        }else {
            data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
        }

        mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED,data.getIsChecked());
        childItems.add(childArrayList);
        parentItems.add(mapParent);

    }

    ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
    ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;

    myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter = new MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(this,parentItems,childItems,false);
    lvCategory.setAdapter(myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter);
}
```

}

**** This is my Fragment Activity ****

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
}

}
```

I'm trying to several days but I can't find how to do...

Any suggestion or help is welcome

Comment: Nothing is complicated about it, just use `getActivity()` in your fragment for context

Comment: what do u mean? i want to transplant it in my fragment 
what context from fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.expandablelistdemo.Model.DataItem;
import com.expandablelistdemo.Model.SubCategoryItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

  private Button btn;
  private ExpandableListView lvCategory;

  private ArrayList<DataItem> arCategory;
  private ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> arSubCategory;
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategoryItem>> arSubCategoryFinal;

  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems;
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems;
  private MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

    setupReferences(view);
    return view;
  }

  private void setupReferences(View view) {

    lvCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);
    arCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    parentItems = new ArrayList<>();
    childItems = new ArrayList<>();

    DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("1");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Adventure");

    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

      SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
      subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(i));
      subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
      subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Adventure: " + i);
      arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }
    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("2");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Art");
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {

      SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
      subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(j));
      subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
      subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Art: " + j);
      arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }
    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.setCategoryId("3");
    dataItem.setCategoryName("Cooking");
    arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int k = 1; k < 6; k++) {

      SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
      subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(k));
      subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
      subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Cooking: " + k);
      arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
    }

    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
    arCategory.add(dataItem);

    Log.d("TAG", "setupReferences: " + arCategory.size());

    for (DataItem data : arCategory) {
//                        Log.i("Item id",item.id);
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      HashMap<String, String> mapParent = new HashMap<String, String>();

      mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID, data.getCategoryId());
      mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME, data.getCategoryName());

      int countIsChecked = 0;
      for (SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem : data.getSubCategory()) {

        HashMap<String, String> mapChild = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_ID, subCategoryItem.getSubId());
        mapChild
            .put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_NAME, subCategoryItem.getSubCategoryName());
        mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID, subCategoryItem.getCategoryId());
        mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, subCategoryItem.getIsChecked());

        if (subCategoryItem.getIsChecked()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {

          countIsChecked++;
        }
        childArrayList.add(mapChild);
      }

      if (countIsChecked == data.getSubCategory().size()) {

        data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
      } else {
        data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
      }

      mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, data.getIsChecked());
      childItems.add(childArrayList);
      parentItems.add(mapParent);

    }

    ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
    ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;

    myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter = new MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(this, parentItems,
        childItems, false);
    lvCategory.setAdapter(myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter);
  }
```